# Sync Framework 2.1 - Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row

Tags: frameworks, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to sync SQL express to a central SQL 2008 r2 database. When I delete a row in the central database and try to sync it to the express database with a download-only scope, it throws the below error:

```
Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.DeletedRowInaccessibleException: Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[DeletedRowInaccessibleException: Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row.]
Microsoft.Synchronization.ISyncSession.Start(CONFLICT_RESOLUTION_POLICY resolutionPolicy, _SYNC_SESSION_STATISTICS& pSyncSessionStatistics) +0
```

Comment: what's your setting for conflict resolution in ApplyChangeFailed event?

Comment: Thanks for the reply June. I have RetryWithForceWrite in the ApplyChangeFailed event.

Comment: I have found the problem to be in the ChangesApplied event where I try to get the deleted row values. I have fixed it by accessing the column value with DataRowVersion.Original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment I found the problem in the ChangesApplied event handler.

Changed the code to access row values from 
    table.Rows[i][j]
to
    table.Rows[i][j, DataRowVersion.Original]

to fix it.

Comment: if it's a deleted row, you only have the PK value to work with. Sync Fx doesn't keep old/original values for deleted rows.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Anyway that works for me. Thanks a lot for your response!